# What's the meaning of "let's not be coy."?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> A man: Perhaps it's fate that today is the fourth of July. 
>   A woman: It's November 12. 
>   The man: Today **let's not be coy**. Let's not be smart or funny or quirky.
>   (At 1:08 from [this video clip](https://youtu.be/mlUsyQzJAHI?t=1m08s))

I found out *coy* has two meanings from a dictionary

> 1. having a shy or sweetly innocent quality that is often intended to be attractive or to get attention
> 2. not telling or revealing all the information that could be revealed

Following these definitions, it could be *Let's not be having a shy* or *Let's revealing all the information*. I think these don't make sense.

What's the meaning of **let's not be coy.**?

Comment: Having seen the clip he's using it in the sense of let's not be reticent about revealing this information ( a picture of his dick) in front of the woman for fear of offending her.

Comment: It's funny because both meanings have been labeled as correct by two different people. Honestly, both are fine in this context. It's just that you had substituted the definitions incorrectly. I would have said, "Let's not be shy or sweetly innocent..." and "Let's not tell or reveal...." Does this help you understand the quote better?

Comment: @ChrisM Thank you for follow up. I have two questions. First, what's the relation between revealing this information and the date. Second, reticent means not willing to tell people about things. So let's not be reticent means let's reveal this information. I mean, Let's not be not willing to tell~ means Let's be willing to tell~.

Comment: @ChrisM Ah. Wait. He ignored her? I thought he replied for her dialog(It's November 12).

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang Ah. Wait. He ignored her? I thought he replied for her dialog(It's November 12)

Comment: @TING CHOE exactly, he's saying let's say this.

Comment: @ChrisM now I got it. Haha. He ignored her!! Haha.